# Windows C socket programming for UDP client

Tags: c, windows, sockets, udp

I am trying to lookup some example programs for windows socket. Particularly, I am interested in writing a client in C (in visual studio) which communicates to the server using UDP. I din't find any concrete material. I tried some examples but got some linking errors. Is there any library available. Please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask *specific* questions on SO. Do you have example code *and the errors* we could help you with?

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) supports sockets, and it is cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple library, which provides implementation of networking, but it is for C++. ([C++ Socket Class for Windows](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/sockets.html)). You can look at it's implementation of working with sockets, or just use it (there are examples of simple client and server).

Comment: I had already looked at that. 2 things: I want to speed up my application and C++/ Java call malloc and do heap transactions which slow down the processes. So, I was thinking of implementing everything in C. As a worst case, I can use this. But I got linking errors LNK2019 Error                                  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___WSAFDIsSet@

Comment: 8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall SocketSelect::Readable(class Socket const * const)" (?Readable@SocketSelect@@QAE_NQBVSocket@@@Z) c:\Users\saurabh17g\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ArdroneSocket\ArdroneSocket\Socket.obj
Looks like I need to link a DLL to support this. Do you have any idea as the way to do that?

Comment: You need to add ws2_32 library to your linker options. Try
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")